# Node MySQL fails to return after a while until restart

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Express on NodeJS to create a RESTful API.

Only I'm noticing at the moment working locally that after a while without Node restarting (including putting Mac to Sleep) that the API fails to return correct data. It only starts to work again after I kill the Node service then to `node app.js` again.

Is this a known thing working locally or should I be worried when going into production?

Comment: What do you mean by "fails to return correct data". Does it return incorrect data, or malfunctions entirely? You need to be more specific about what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to put it to production when it dies locally, it may be a serious memory leak and can disrupt other services running on the server.

I would put a debugging info in the function, where it should return a data, to see, where it fails. Take a look at https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'm giving it a go running `node server/app.js --debug` to see if there are any issues.